# error: <atomic> is not implemented in LLVM version 5.1

Tags: c++11, cmake, llvm, osx-mountain-lion, atomic

I'm trying to compile [libcxxabi](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/) with cmake, and running into issues.  I believe that this is because I don't have a separate copy of llvm installed that has llvm-config.  So I've checked out llvm, and am trying to [build that with cmake](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#quick-start).  I get the error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:37 (message):
  Host Clang must be able to find libstdc++4.7 or newer!
```

And cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:37 is literally a block like:

```
check_cxx_source_compiles("
#include <atomic>
std::atomic<float> x(0.0f);
int main() { return (float)x; }"
    LLVM_NO_OLD_LIBSTDCXX)
if(NOT LLVM_NO_OLD_LIBSTDCXX)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Host Clang must be able to find libstdc++4.7 or newer!")
endif()
```

and if I try to compile the 3 liner with the compiler flag `-std=c++0x` (which is higher up in the cmake file) I get the error:

```
atomic.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'atomic' file not found
#include <atomic>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How is it that I don't have support for c++11 atomics?  I'm running OSX 10.8.5, upgraded from 10.8.4, and XCode version 5.1.1, and clang++ 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn).  I have no options to upgrade xcode in the app store, nor the developer tools.  Do I need to reinstall XCode, or upgrade to Mavericks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to check out all of LLVM and pass an additonal command line argument to CMake.

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd ../projects
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBCXX=ON
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with xCode 6.4. When using atomic in a simple helloWorld program it worked, but when using a project generated by CMake, I had the "#error is not implemented"

It appears CMake needs special flags to enable c++11 on mac... So, did exactly (almost... replaced if(UNIX) by if(APPLE)) as kitware indicates here:

https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/C%2B%2B11Flags

In case the link stops working one day....

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(Test)

if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()

# MSVC does not require any special flags
```